# Django - how to delete model item from list

Tags: python, django

I'm currently building an app with Django for the purpose of creating user-story cards (a bit like a Trello board).

On one page I have my cards displayed as a list:

[image]

The code for the list is:

```
<h1>ScrumBuddy Board</h1>
   <ul>
          {% for card in cards.all %}
              <li class="card"><a href="{% url 'card' %}/{{ card.id }}">{{ card.title }}</a>
             </li>
          {% endfor %}

   </ul>
```

And the view def for the board is:

```
def board(request):
    cards = Card.objects
    context = {'cards': cards}
    return render(request, 'scrumbuddy/board.html', context)
```

I'd like to add a delete link to each card that removes it from this list, preferable with a confirmation dialogue box. Any suggestions on how to do that would be fantastic.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using Django's generic class-based views, in your case you would probably use `ListView` and `DeleteView`.

For a list view, you could use something like this:

```
# views.py
from django.views.generic import ListView
from scrumbuddy.models import Card

class CardList(ListView):
    model = Card
```

And for the delete view something like this:

```
# views.py
from django.views.generic.edit import DeleteView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from scrumbuddy.models import Card

class CardDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Card
    success_url = reverse_lazy('card-list')
```

As far as the confirmation for the delete action goes, from the Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#deleteview) on the `DetailView` topic:

> A view that displays a confirmation page and deletes an existing
>   object. The given object will only be deleted if the request method is
>   POST. If this view is fetched via GET, it will display a confirmation
>   page that should contain a form that POSTs to the same URL.

Also, note that you can pass arguments to the `url` template tag, e.g.:

```
<a href="{% url 'card' id=card.id %}">
```

instead of:

```
<a href="{% url 'card' %}/{{ card.id }}">
```

Note: I guessed that the `card.id` parameter to your `card` url is named `id` - you'll have to update this as per your `urls.py` if the parameter is named differently.

Comment: Thanks for the reply bonidjukic - but I get a NoReverseMatch at /scrumbuddy/board error when I tried your code.

Comment: @Lylio, my mistake, I used the `card-list` url name as an example for the delete view success redirect and accidentally used it in the `url` example at the end of the answer as well. I edited the post to fix this.

Comment: I see, thanks. But this still gives the error -  I think my views/urls is incorrect. My url for the card is - url(r'^card', views.card, name='card'), and the card def is - def card(request): return render(request, 'scrumbuddy/card.html'). How should I include the card.id info into these sections?

Comment: You should probably use something like this: `url(r'^cards/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.card, name='card')`, then you'll be able to use the `url` as I mentioned above (of course, in your view you should receive that `id` from the `request` and load the appropriate Card to return to the template).

Comment: " in your view you should receive that id from the request and load the appropriate Card to return to the template" < sorry I'm a little unsure of this part, could you give an example of what the view should look like? Thanks.